# "Unable to read file" when running any gsutil command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

When I try and use any gsutil command on my google cloud instance, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gsutil) Unable to read file [/snap/google-cloud-sdk/217/platform/gsutil/VERSION]: [Er
rno 2] No such file or directory: '/snap/google-cloud-sdk/217/platform/gsutil/VERSION'
```

Comment: I’m afraid your question is not elaborated enough to help you with your problem. We need to know what you're trying to achieve, if you are running a code (post the code), and what command you are executing. The error can mean several things, so we need to have more information. Welcome to Stack Overflow!!

Comment: That looks like a problem with the Google SDK install, can you also share how you installed the SDK on your machine and what OS you're using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you've installed a pre-release version of the package which doesn't have the `snap/google-cloud-sdk/217/platform/gsutil/VERSION` file (it doesn't have the `snap/google-cloud-sdk/217/platform/` folder at all) which the `gsutil` seems to need.
This is still a problem on the the current edge release of 370:

> (gsutil) Unable to read file
> [/snap/google-cloud-sdk/221/platform/gsutil/VERSION]: [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> '/snap/google-cloud-sdk/221/platform/gsutil/VERSION'

Removing the package with
`sudo snap remove google-cloud-sdk`
and installing the stable version with
`sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic` fixed this error for me.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This worked for me, but I did have to change the first line to "sudo snap remove google-cloud-sdk"

Comment: Oh that was a dumb typo on my part! Thanks for pointing it out, I've edited the answer to correct it.